# Apply SelectMany to three or more sequences

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best way to apply `SelectMany` to get a cross join of three or more sequences  using only extension methods? Is there any other way to get a cross join?

**Test Data**

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(11, 2);
var b = Enumerable.Range(21, 2);
var c = Enumerable.Range(31, 2);
```

**Expected Result**

```
 X  Y  Z 

11 21 31 
11 21 32 
11 22 31 
11 22 32 
12 21 31 
12 21 32 
12 22 31 
12 22 32
```

**What I tried**

Here's the code that works but I wonder if there's any alternative that'd be easier to read and understand:

```
var d = a
    .SelectMany(rb => b
    .SelectMany(rc => c, (y, z) => new { Y = y, Z = z}), 
                        (x, yz) => new { X = x, Y = yz.Y, Z = yz.Z });
```

The equivalent query expression is good but not what I'm looking for:

```
var e = from x in a
        from y in b
        from z in c
        select new { X = x, Y = y, Z = z };
```

Comment: Why do you say that the last query expression is not what you're looking for ? In my opinion is the cleanest and easiest to read (and I'm really a fan of LINQ methods syntax...)

Comment: So you cannot create any new method at all but just have to write it out every time ? Am I understanding the restrictions correctly?

Comment: @digEmAll Yes, it's much cleaner and easiest to read, it's just out of scope of this question. I just have a feeling that I miss something about the extension method syntax, that's all.

Comment: @Esailija I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @SergeBelov I am wondering why do you write it manually, when you can just make a method like `d = CrossJoin( a, b, c ...)`? You cannot get easier to read and write than that...

Comment: @Esailija I've essentially asked how to implement such a method, haven't I?

Comment: @SergeBelov then why did you accept an answer that requires you to manually write the code everytime? It's just confusing. You also said that you don't want to use LINQ... but what does it matter what the method `CrossJoin` uses for its implementation? Everything in your question is hinting towards better manual implementation, implying that custom method is unacceptable.

Comment: @Esailija Which `CrossJoin` method are you referring to? Would you care to share a link? I'm not aware of one in `System.Linq`.

Comment: @SergeBelov I didn't say such method existed out of the box. Just saying one can write such a method, and after that you can use it to cross join any amount of sequences with little code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify (even if not much) your `SelectMany` query in this way:

```
var res = a.SelectMany(X => b.SelectMany(Y => c.Select(Z => new { X, Y, Z })));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Join` that projects keys that always match.

```
var e = a.Join(b, x => true, y => true, (x, y) => new { A = x, B = y })
         .Join(c, x => true, y => true, (x, y) => new { x.A, x.B, C = y });
```

Admittedly, it's probably less efficient than your `SelectMany` version.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I didn't think of using `Join`.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure if it's ok to make a custom method. But here it is anyway:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CrossJoin<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    foreach (var sequence in sequences)
    {
        result = result.SelectMany(i => sequence.Select(s => i.Concat(new[] { s })));
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you add such a method, then the code that matters will become very readable:

```
var d = CrossJoin(
    Enumerable.Range(11, 2),
    Enumerable.Range(21, 2),
    Enumerable.Range(31, 2)
);
```

Result:

```
Console.WriteLine("X  Y  Z");
foreach( var item in d ) {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join( ",", item ));
}
/*
X  Y  Z
11,21,31
11,21,32
11,22,31
11,22,32
12,21,31
12,21,32
12,22,31
12,22,32
*/
```

Comment: I know see what you meant. That's good suggestion, too, thanks.